# Object #<Object> has no method 'showModalDialog'

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, dialog-framework

Consider the following code:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Create a new Post'
    autoSize: true,
    url: url
}

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

The code is executed from a ECB custom action and from a web part. It works fine in IE, however when i call it from the webpart in Google Chrome it gives the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'showModalDialog'

The strange thing is that when i call the exact same code (it's part of my library) from the ECB custom action it now works in Google Chrome!

I've tried calling it with

- `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`
- `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("funcname")`
- `LoadSodByKey("sp.ui.dialog.js", null);`

Any ideas or help? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: How are you calling it from your webpart? On page load?

Comment: no, button click event. i attach to it using jquery... i understand the error, the dialog module has not been fully loaded, but i dont understand why its happening as it works with IE perfectly...

Comment: Any other errors in the console? Is the web part on the same page as the custom action?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but I implemented the following to fix the issue with the scrollbar not appearing in Chrome. Perhaps it's related: http://withinsharepoint.com/archives/256

Comment: no, no other errors. no they are not on the same page. thanks for the link, will try it out and let you know!

Comment: Did that fix it? The fact that it's not working on the web part page makes me think that there's an issue specific to that page. Are you using a different master page? Perhaps sp.js is not being loaded at all, is it referenced on the page (do a view source)?

Comment: ok - i've tried it and it seemed to work, however, from time to time i still get this issue. i honestly believe its an chrome cache issue, because i deployed your fix and it was working perfectly, then added something entirely different (not even .js code) and deployed it and all of the sudden it did not work anymore!!! no, i am using the default master page on a newly created web app (no other customization other than this code!). i can confirm that sp.js is loaded, because i can get the current ctx or use SP.ListOperation.Selection just fine.

Comment: in the end i used jquery ui for the dialogs, because SP's dialog framework is just s..t

Comment: have u try with $(document).load() ?

Comment: yes and it gives the same error. i can confirm that the document is properly loaded because all other js api things do work, its just the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chrome issue with it's caching model.

Please make sure you call

```
LoadSodByKey("SP.UI.Dialog.js", null);
```

To ensure the file is loaded.

Comment: thanks, i already tried that though and it did not work. see my initial post

Comment: This is the correct fix for the issue, where did you run this code? If it isn't working then there is something else wrong perhaps to many async calls?

Comment: from within a Web Part (in an external js file, though).. i do agree, but i never got it to work like this in Chrome. I think thats a specific issue with Chrome, because it works with every other browser just fine, so i will mark your answer as correct anyway.

Comment: perhaps the key was wrong? You can jump into the console and take a look at the SP.SOD dictionary object

Answer (score 0):

This specified error that is encountered in Chrome browser, could be eliminated by using  [SP.SOD.execute(key, functionName, args) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407807%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Replace the line

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

with the

```
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```